# Setting timeout in $http Service AngularJS 1.5.5

Tags: angularjs

I have my controller calling the api and by the time the api returns results I have the 500 Internal server in the chrome console popping up. I am using angular 1.5.5, could you please help with some timeout code.

Tried using `.timeout(3000,new Error(timeout exceeded))` before `.then` but it does not compile

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('submitService',function($http)){
    var service={};
    service.getJwtToken=function(user)
    {
        return $http({
            method: "POST",
            url:"http://localhost:5000/jwtTest",
            data: user
        }).then(function(resp){
            return resp;
        });
    }
    return service;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try with setInterval

```
 setInterval(function () {
//Call your Service here
}, 5000);
```

This server error occurs because there may be missing param or something like this

```
//if  'function2' is dependent on any condition of 'function1' call like this

var f1 = yourService.function1(param1);
    f1.then(function (data1) {  
        if(data1){
        var f2 = yourService.function2(param2);
            f2.then(function (data2) {
            //Do code
                    });
                }
        });

//if  'function2' and 'function1' are independent call like this

var f1 = yourService.function1(param1);
    f1.then(function (data1) {
    //Do code
            });
var f2 = yourService.function2(param2);
    f2.then(function (data2) {
    //Do code
            });
```

Comment: just for clarification....if multiple function calles are nested with the api call, is it most likely to give rise to timeout issues? If I debug the associated service it runs normally, but when the api is hit, it always results in a 500 internal server error.

Answer (score 0):

To set a timeout of for the $http service, use the `timeout` property of the config object:

```
app.factory('submitService', function ($http) {
    var service = {};
    service.getJwtToken = function (user) {
        var config = { timeout: 3000 };
        return $http.post("http://localhost:5000/jwtTest", user, config);
    };
    return service;
});
```

From the Docs:

> ### config object
>
> Object describing the request to be made and how it should be processed. The object has following properties:
>
> - **timeout** – `{number|Promise}` – timeout in milliseconds, or [promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) that should abort the request when resolved.
>
>   A numerical timeout or a promise returned from [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout), will set the `xhrStatus` in the [response](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#$http-returns) to "timeout", and any other resolved promise will set it to "abort", following standard XMLHttpRequest behavior.

For more information, see

- [AngularJS $http Service API Reference - Arguments](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#$http-arguments)